# Show JSF error page for exceptions when user tampers with form submits

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I am trying to show an generic error message page when a user tampers with POST data in a richfaces calendar. (Using tamper data firefox plugin).

I select a normal date, turn on the tamper and adjust the date value to contain string values. It returns to the page displaying the following error messages:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2012dsafsf"
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2012sdfsdf"
```

I'm using `<h:messages />` to display messages.

I have added the following to my web.xml but it is not redirecting to this page.

```
<error-page>
  <exception-type>java.lang.NumberFormatException</exception-type>
  <location>/error.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

What I essentially need is a generic class/phase listener/converter/whatever.. to intercept and handle certain types of exceptions that are caught by JSF. (Not unhandled exceptions).

Thanks

Comment: Are you sending an asynchronous (ajax) or synchronous (normal) request? Is this JSF 1.x or 2.x?

Comment: I'm  sending a synchronous request using JSF 2.0 BalsusC.

Comment: @BalsusC - See my last comment. Just getting back to this now again. I'm basically trying to redirect any exceptions of this type to an error page. Do I need to create a phase listener to intercept the message?  I currently have an ExceptionHandlerWrapper setup to cater for unhandled exceptions. Could this be used to intercept these type of exceptions also?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to fix it is to add a validator to the field. With the validator it is possible to add a specific message for this error.

Some information on Validation & conversion: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jsf3/

The error documents are used for HTTP status codes (e.g. 404/500)

Comment: Thanks Mark, I created a validator and this works BUT I would also like to know why my web.xml changes are not been picked up.

Comment: I guess the exception thrown is wrapped in an other type of exception. a javax.servlet.ServletException is a good test. But again this is guess.